# Run "tasks" in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS 2017 to work on an Azure DevOps Repo that storages some SQL Server stored procedures, among other code. I want to write a script to:

- open one or more stored procedures
- comment 1 line
- change the head from `CREATE PROCEDURE` to `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`
- connect to the DB and execute the procedure

Is it possible to create/execute this in VS?

Comment: *"connect to the DB and execute the procedure"* This'll be very difficult; where are you going to get the values for the parameters for the procedure? They are likely going to be different for each procedure.

Comment: They will CREATE/ALTER the procedure. The objective is to change these procedures in the DB from VS